# stationary non-isotropic spatial stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Are there any interesting examples of second order stationary processes on ${\mathcal R}^2$ or ${\mathcal R}^3$ that are not isotropic? The book I am looking at has no examples.

Update : I asked this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47684/stationary-non-isotropic-spatial-stochastic-processes) in mathoverflow, apparently such examples are not easy to come by.

Update: Processes with [anisotropic variograms](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZvoibTTS9QwC&pg=PA113&dq=anisotropic+variograms&hl=en&ei=fvbzTMm-I8WqlAeP4aX0DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=anisotropic%2520variograms&f=false) are examples of non-isotropic stationary processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, lots of them. Consider for example some independent stationary processes $U=(U_x)_{x\in\mathbb R}$ and $V=(V_y)_{y\in\mathbb R}$ and define $X_{x,y}=U_x+V_y$ for every $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Then $X=(X_{x,y})_{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2}$ is invariant under the effect of every translation but not under the effect of the rotation of angle $\frac\pi2$, that is, unless $U$ and $V$ are identically distributed.